# What are the canonical font weights in Core Text?

Tags: macos, cocoa, fonts, core-text, nsfont

Both [GDI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Pango](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Fonts.html#PangoWeight) have a list of canonical font weights that go in the range "thin, extra light, light, normal, medium, semibold, bold, extra bold, heavy". It appears [CSS does too](http://www.elliotjaystocks.com/blog/font-weight-in-the-age-of-web-fonts/).

However, I don't see such a font list for Core Text (or even NSFont/NSFontDescriptor) on OS X. Instead, what I see is

- `kCTFontWeightTrait`, which is documented as going from -1.0 to 1.0 with 0.0 being "regular or medium" (so both normal and medium or just medium?), and
- `-[NSFontManager fontWithFamily:traits:weight:size:]`, whose weight parameter is documented as going from 0 to 15 with 5 being normal/book (which I assume is between light and normal, if not normal) and 9 and higher all being bold

So what are the equivalents of the above canonical weight names? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical names are given in the headers:

```
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightUltraLight NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightThin NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightLight NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightRegular NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightMedium NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightSemibold NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightBold NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightHeavy NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
APPKIT_EXTERN const CGFloat NSFontWeightBlack NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_11);
```

To learn their values, just log each one in turn.

```
NSLog(@"%f", NSFontWeightUltraLight);
NSLog(@"%f", NSFontWeightThin);
// ... need I go on?
```

Comment: Oh neat. Which header is this? I completely missed it when I looked earlier today >////>

Comment: Oh wait I just realized why I missed it: I only have the 10.10 headers :/ Surprised they were only added now...

Comment: There were no canonical weights until now, I think.

Comment: Yep, [this](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/2023wpov1sxpnf9/202/202_whats_new_in_cocoa.pdf) confirms it. Thanks! Since I need to run on 10.7 and higher I'll just get the values of the constants out of a 10.11 box and switch to using the constants directly if my requirements ever change.